# Play 2.5 + Slick + DI Issue

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have DAO defined as follows:

```
@Singleton
class MyDAO @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile]  {
```

I have an integration test which references this DAO:

```
class SomeIntegrationTest {
  lazy val someVal = new MyDAO
}
```

How can I inject the `DatabaseConfigProvider` into the `MyDAO` in the SomeIntegrationTest? I cannot inject one in the constructor of the test because test classes do not take constructor parameters.

Comment: Would it make any sense to inject MyDAO in your test? This way the DIC will do the dependency work for you.

Comment: @hasumedic, how would I do that?

Comment: Something along the lines of `class SomeIntegrationTest @Inject()(val someVal: MyDAO)`. I've no idea if this would work, it's just a suggestion. The other more regular solution to this is to have testing versions (stubs, mocks) of `DatabaseConfigProvider` that you can use when setting up your tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your dependency injected by doing

```
val dbConfigProvider = app.injector.instanceOf[DatabaseConfigProvider]
```

where `app` is an instance of your [FakeApplication](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithScalaTest#FakeApplication). Without it, there is no way Play can inject your dependency for you. You can get an instance of `FakeApplication` by extending `OneAppPerSuite`, see the provided link for more details.

In general, there are three main ways you can gain access to some object(s) in your test:

- manual creation of objects using the new keyword (not considered best practice)
- injection via injector as shown here (either injecting objects directly or injecting a provider/factory which can get them for you)
- in case of unit testing a class with some dependencies, having those dependencies [mocked](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWithScalaTest#Mockito)